# ReCaptcha always asking for extra verification?

Tags: php, recaptcha

[image]

For a project, I recently installed the new 2.0 version of ReCaptcha. I added the keys and secret to the Developer Panel, and installed the widget in my form.

It works perfectly, but with one little problem:
The Captcha is always asking for a second verification. It's nice to users if they only see the green tick, but after clicking the Captcha, it comes with the extra picture verification...

So what's the problem here? Google not trusting my IP? How to check?

[image]

Comment: Can you display the code where you initalize the captcha?

Comment: I saw that claim made by google about the new re-captcha, but frankly: I have never, not a single time experienced a page where that actually worked. It _always_ enters the second verification stage is my impression. not sure why, because of setup issues or because it is generally broken. That does not really make a difference, since a tool obviously that hard to use that it _never_ works as expeced is broken be design.

Comment: @arkascha - just one more flop from Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to a [WIRED article](http://www.wired.com/2014/12/google-one-click-recaptcha/), Google is (amongst other indications) using IP addresses and cookies to recognize you.

> Instead of depending upon the traditional distorted word test,
> Google’s “reCaptcha” examines cues every user unwittingly provides: IP
> addresses and cookies provide evidence that the user is the same
> friendly human Google remembers from elsewhere on the Web. And Shet
> says even the tiny movements a user’s mouse makes as it hovers and
> approaches a checkbox can help reveal an automated bot.

In your browser settings, you have most likely disabled third-party cookies, which will prevent Google from recognizing you. Add `*.google.com` to your whitelist, and the image-based verification won't show up again.

Comment: Invisible Recaptca claims to be the universal panacea for getting rid of image selection verification but in my tests, like the OP, it continues to ask for image verification. So, it is apparently more one half-cooked stuff from Google. Google should stop doing a lot of bad stuff at the same time and start doing less things right. All their projects are spectacular flops.

Comment: First, many thanks for your answer. It did worked. However I have other PC on which my browser does not accept third party cookie from google. and the recaptcha does not show up either. This is quit weird.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a second verification. If your client's IP address is in google white-list, nothing will appear but the green tick. Otherwise they have to answer the security question.

**It's not a bug, it's a feature!**

For more information look here: https://www.funcaptcha.com/2015/01/06/recaptcha-is-still-vulnerable-perhaps-even-more-than-ever-before/

Comment: And how does a system get whitelisted? I mean we are talking about the web here, not some LAN-internal apps or something. For such a captcha is senseless anyway.

Comment: That is pathetic. I am expected to answer a captcha _several times_, and _then_ I am whitelisted? In a web environment, where one always stumbles over a captcha only once? Or do you mean it collects all my experiences with all captchas on all pages I visited, so a clear violation of privacy rules? Sorry no, as I said: not a feature, but broken by design.

Comment: @arkascha User’s past behavior and previous CAPTCHA solves are recorded in their cookies, which are then detected by future reCAPTCHA challenges. Those that are seen as being genuine users get the “No CAPTCHA experience”, while those that aren’t get reverted back to the usual distorted text reCAPTCHA.